# Spring batch for large files(1billion to 5billion flat file data)

Tags: spring-batch

I have a large file which may contain 1billion to 5billion records. I am planning to use chunk oriented processing and my thought is

1) Split the large file into smaller based on the count let say 10K in each file.

2) If there are 1billion records then I will get 10000 files each containing 10K records

3) I would like to partition these 10000 files and would like to process using 10 threads. I used custom MultiResourcePartioner

4) The 10 threads should process all the 10000 files created in split process.

5) I don't want to create same number of threads equal to file count as in that case I may face memory issues. What I am looking is whatever the number of files I would like to process them using only 10 threads.

Expert could you let me know this can be achieved using spring batch? If yes could you please share pointers or reference implementations.

Example:

```
<bean id="transformPartitioner"
    class="com.example.transformers.partition.TransformerPartitioner">
    <property name="outputPath" value="${output.directory}" />
</bean>

<bean id="loadTransformData" class="com.example.transformers.step.LoadTransformData"
    factory-method="reader" scope="step">
    <constructor-arg value="#{stepExecutionContext[outputFile]}" />
</bean>

<bean id="processTransformData" class="com.example.transformers.step.ProcessTransformData"
    scope="step">
    <property name="threadName" value="#{stepExecutionContext[threadName]}" />
    <property name="sourceFileName" value="#{jobParameters[filename]}" />       
</bean>

<bean id="notifyToJMS" class="com.example.transformers.step.NotifyToJMS"
    scope="step">
    <property name="fileName" value="#{stepExecutionContext[outputFile]}" />
</bean>

<bean id="outputFileDeletingTasklet"
    class="com.example.transformers.step.OutputFileDeletingTasklet"
    scope="step">
    <property name="directory" value="file:${output.directory}" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope" />

<bean id="jobRepository"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="jobLauncher"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />
```

Custom Multi resource partitioned:

```
public Map<String, ExecutionContext> partition(int gridSize) {

    int index = 0;
    File directory = new File(outputPath);
    File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
    Map result = new HashMap(gridSize);

    for (File file : fList) {
        if (file.isFile()) {
            ExecutionContext exContext = new ExecutionContext();
            logger.info(loggerClassName+" Starting : Thread [" + index + "] for file : " + file.getName());
            exContext.put(constants.THREAD_NAME, "Thread" + index);
            exContext.put(constants.OUTPUT_FILE, outputPath + file.getName());
            exContext.put(constants.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, file.getName());
            result.put(constants.PARTITION + index, exContext);
            index++;
        }
    }
```

Appreciate your response.

Comment: I think the number of people who have dealt with numbers that large is quite small. The world could probably use more experts in processing billions of records using Spring Batch so try it and see what happens...then report back :)

Comment: I am not sure how to resolve this issue. No way to control partitions? is there any possible as a batch wise.  like example first batch 100 partitions for 100 files and second batch 100 partitions next 100 files.. so...on..  My requirement is have 1Billion to 5Billion records as flat a file data

Comment: @Sai: Sorry , I was very busy. Your answer should be a comment to my answer and not an answer in itself.Glad that your problem is resolved.

Comment: I am new for this app. Going forward I will follow the same. Thanks a lot Sabir.

Answer (score 0):

First read my [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43809682/3850730) to understand that Spring Batch doesn't perform well if number of partitions goes beyond 100 i.e. Spring Batch API itself starts taking too much time to prepare data in meta tables . This is beyond comprehension but that is the way it is.

Secondly, you are correct in splitting a large file into smaller files - that is the way to go about it. In this pre processing , you might wish to assign an identifier to each file name so those can be easily grouped later.

The part where you are incorrect is about creating as many partitions as number of files - if you have 10k files and if Spring Batch API takes forever to create meta data for 1000 partitions, you can imagine how will it behave for 10k partitions.

What you have to do is fix your number of partitions in job where one partition means a group of files instead of a single file. This is up to you as how you want to achieve that grouping. Lets say 50 partitions so you will divide your 10K files into 50 groups means - 200 files for each partition.

In your code, you are using `gridSize` to only initialize map, use it to fix your number of partitions.

Now Spring Batch gives you a choice as how many partitions you wish to start in parallel ( your point# 5 ) - Read step # 3 of [my this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42337428/3850730). You can either use an Async task executor or a thread pool. Parallelism depends on your server capacity.

This way your one thread will process a bunch of files instead of one and so on. Out of total partitions only few will remain active at a time and rest will be in **Not - Started** state.

Comment: Sorry to reply late.. I was on vacation and thanks for providing the information. I have added the group of files to partition.. However how to read the multiple files in item reader? for(int i=temp;i<fList.length && temp<fList.length; i++) { l.add("file:"+outputPath + fList[i].getName());temp=i;
    if(l.size()==50) {
     temp++;
     break;
    }}ExecutionContext exContext = new ExecutionContext();exContext.put(ECDCConstants.OUTPUT_FILE, l);

Comment: Could you please provide sample example for one thread will process a bunch of files?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue based on batch bases. I fixed the partitions limit to 100 and each partition will responsible to complete multiple files.
1) Added multiple files into each partition.
2) Implemented multi resource item reader to read multiple files and delegate to item reader.

Thanks for suggestion Sabir!!!.